# Automapper causing error: missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: entity-framework-6, nuget-package, automapper-3

I am new to Automapper.

I have added Nuget package - Automapper into my Manager (BLL) and DAL layer.

Now, below is related stuff:

Below is the statment of Manager library that giving me exception:

```
this.dataRepository.Update(Mapper.Map<StudentMaster>(studentDTO));
```

Exception is as follow:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types:
>   studentDTO -> StudentMaster
>   Admin.App.DTO.studentDTO-> Admin.App.DAL.StudentMaster

In case of select/where query on EF, it is working and able to map using

```
.Project().To<TReturn>()
```

I wrote an `Autoconfiguration.cs` file as follows:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        ConfigureStudentMasterMaps();
    }

    private static void ConfigureStudentMasterMaps()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<StudentMaster, studentDTO>();                  
    }
}
```

Note:

Both the entity - `StudentMaster` (model) entity and `StudentDTO` have the same properties.

Please guide me how I could resolve this issue.

Thank You

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See Getting-started https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started

```
CreateMap<**TSource, TDestination**>()
```

You must add

```
Mapper.CreateMap<studentDTO, StudentMaster>();
```

After mapping configuration call

```
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Comment: Thank You , it works. so, do i have to add this statement on each time while doing UPDATE, INSERT operaton when require to pass Model(mapped) object ?? Or, i should add this into AutoConfiguration.cs file.... keep both the statement - `Mapper.CreateMap<StudentMaster, studentDTO>();` `Mapper.CreateMap<studentDTO,StudentMaster>();`

Comment: You maping registers once and can use any number of times in the subsequent.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I forgot to register in the Global.asax

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);


        AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings();

    }
}
```